# PrettyPrint python into a string, and not stdout

Tags: python

I'd like to use prettyprint to print out a dictionary, but into a string and not to console.
This string is to be passed on to other functions.

I know I can use the "stream" parameter to specify a file instead of sys.out but I want a string.

How do I do that?

Comment: `s=pprint.pformat(your_dict)`

Comment: @thias that doesn't include newlines.

Comment: @Fabian yes it does. Simply specify the width parameter.

Comment: @Simon correct, my testing data was not big enough.

Comment: @eran can you please fix the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [`StringIO` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Now you may pass `output` as a stream to `prettyprint`.

Answer (score 105):

You should simply call the pformat function from the pprint module:

```
import pprint
s = pprint.pformat(aDict)
```

Comment: much more pythonic than going via `StringIO`, IMHO

Comment: I agree. I didn't know about this option of `pprint`.

Comment: This needs to be set as the correct answer since the request is for pprint as a string, pformat is **the** method for this. Its provided for exactly this purpose by the pprint module.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is not chosen as the correct answer

Answer (score 9):

I sometimes use the `json` module for that:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{'a':1}}

In [3]: s = json.dumps(d, indent=4)

In [4]: s
Out[4]: '{\n    "a": 1, \n    "c": {\n        "a": 1\n    }, \n    "b": 2\n}'

In [5]: print s
{
    "a": 1, 
    "c": {
        "a": 1
    }, 
    "b": 2
}
```

Comment: try `d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{'a':[1,2,3,4]}}`. I don't think it works well for arbitrary python objects as `pprint` does

Comment: @thias -- there are some limitations [has to be JSON serializable], but it works fine with the example you gave.

Comment: @thias -- with nested dicts I actually think it looks better from the aesthetic point of view :)